# ImageMagick: cannot convert 24-bit bmp image to 8-bit bmp image

Tags: php, imagemagick

My programming platform is:

- Ubuntu 3.19
- ImageMagick 6.7.7
- Programming language: php

My code:

```
$img = new Imagick($image_input_24bit_bmp);
$img->setimagedepth(8);
$img->writeImage($image_output);
```

Then image_output is still 24-bit bmp image.

The thing I would like is convert the 24-bit bmp image to the 8-bit bmp image.
Thanks.

Comment: Please post an example 8-bit image of the type you want to get out of ImageMagick - it seems your idea of an 8-bit image doesn't to match mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `setImageDepth` just isn't enough. You need to `quanitize` the image.

Example:Test Script

```
$im = new imagick('stupid.png'); //an image of mine
$im->setImageFormat('PNG8');
$colors = min(255, $im->getImageColors());
$im->quantizeImage($colors, Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB, 0, false, false );
$im->setImageDepth(8 /* bits */);
$im->writeImage('stupid8.png');
```

Comment: Even I followed your suggestion. Its not working. My output image was still 24-bit bmp.

Comment: can you upload those image?? so that we can test it?

Answer (score 1):

You can force an 8-bit palettised BMP image (which is what I presume you mean) like this:

```
$im = new imagick('input.bmp');
$im->quantizeImage(256,Imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB,0,false,false);
$im->writeImage('result.bmp');
```

That will have a palette of 256 colours (each one 8-bit Red, plus 8-bit Green, plus 8-bit Blue), and each pixel will be represented by its index into that palette.

Comment: It's better to request 255 colors, to leave room in the palette for the "background color" which occupies one entry if it isn't among the resulting quantized palette.

Comment: This was not working for me. My output image was still 24-bit bmp.